# Swift and CSVImporter: Only the first row of .csv is being imported

Tags: swift, csv

I am trying to import a csv and parse it using CSVImporter. However, when I print the object array's count, it only imports 1 out of 20 rows.

I've tried using the "Header Structure" method from the CSVImporter example, but that gives me the same problem. I think it may have something to do with the CSV itself and maybe the special characters are screwing it up, but I'm not able to alter the CSV in any way.

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Departments", ofType: "csv")
        let importer = CSVImporter<Department>(path: path!)
        importer.startImportingRecords { recordValues -> Department in

            return Department(name: recordValues[0], advisingInfo: recordValues[1], calendar: recordValues[2], chair: recordValues[3], icon: recordValues[4], office: recordValues[5], summary: recordValues[6], tutorLink: recordValues[7], url: recordValues[8])

            }.onFinish { importedRecords in

                for dept in importedRecords {
                    // Now importedRecords is an array of Departments
                    print(importedRecords.count) // returns 1 which is the first department (Sociology...)
                }
```

First 3 entries in CSV as printed out in the console ("Sociology, Economics and Anthropology","Psychology and Education", and "Nursing")

```
Name,AdvisingInfo,Calendar,Chair,Icon,Office,Summary,TutorLink,URL,ChairPhone,AdvismentLink
"Sociology, Economics and Anthropology",You have chosen a major in the Sociology,,Dr. Jill Null,ic_soc,Null Hall NH 200,"The Department of Sociology, Economics and Anthropology offers a 
rich variety of sociology, anthropology, economics, geography, and 
human services courses. The department offers courses that are 
required in many of the degree programs at County College of 
Null, including the Liberal Arts and Business degree. The
department's experienced faculty members have a broad range of 
interests and expertise, as reflected in the many electives available 
in the department.",,https://www.null.edu/,973-555-5610,https://www.null.edu/student-life/
Psychology and Education,"You have chosen a major in the Psychology and Education 
Department.

As a full-time student you must meet with an Academic Advisor 
to receive advisement clearance before registering for classes 
each semester. As a part-time student you are encouraged to
 meet with an Academic Advisor on a regular basis (although 
clearance to register is not necessary). In order to build a 
relationship and have continuity in your educational planning, it 
is advisable to meet with the same faculty member each 
semester for advisement.

For students majoring in Humanities Social Sciences/Liberal Arts 
(P1130), contact the office of the Dean of Liberal Arts, Dr Bob 
Null, Cohen Hall 253, bnull@mail.edu, 973-555-5555, and you 
will be referred to a specific faculty member(s) for academic 
advisement.

Registration for the spring and fall semesters begins in early 
November and April, respectively. Be on the look out for more
information about ""Advisement Week"" for your department/
major.",,Josh Null,ic_psych,Null Hall NH 200,"The Department of Psychology and Education is a member of the 
Division of Liberal Arts. It is comprised of courses and programs in 
(a) psychology, (b) early childhood education and (c) teacher 
education. The department supports the liberal arts curriculum and 
the college’s overall mission to provide students with transferable 
liberal arts courses, courses to fulfill the general education 
requirements in numerous curricula, providing a comprehensive 
background in the behavioral sciences.",,https://www.null.edu/academics/,973-555-5555,https://www.null.edu/student-life/
Nursing,"Academic Advisors are available to help you select the courses that 
best support your educational and career goals as well as provide 
direction to the many resources and support services available at 
the college. Each semester, full-time students pursuing a degree at 
CCM must see their Academic Advisor(s) to obtain advisement 
clearance in order to register for classes.",,Dr. K. Lucy Null,ic_nursing,Null Hall NH 300,"The Nursing program is fully accredited by the Accreditation 
Commission for Education in Nursing. Graduates of the program are 
granted an Associate in Applied Science degree and have attained 
the academic requirements to apply for the National Council 
Licensing Examination (NCLEX) and Registered Nurse Licensure. 
The program offers a balance of general education and nursing 
courses to prepare students for Registered Nurse positions.",http://www.null.edu/academics/,https://www.null.edu/academics,973-555-5555,https://www.null.edu/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by just using CSwiftV instead of CSVImporter. https://github.com/Daniel1of1/CSwiftV